# JavaScript regexp get a word between texts

Tags: javascript, regex, custom-controls

In javascript I need to get the text within the custom tag. For example

> [tag_**retweet** attr="val" attr2="val"]

In this case I need to get the word "retweet" only skipping all other texts and another example is,

> [tag_**share**]

Here I need to get the word "share".

So what will be the regexp for getting that tag name in my case ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like `/\[tag_([a-z0-9_]+)(?:\s+|\])/`

```
var tag = '[tag_retweet attr="val" attr2="val"]';
var match = tag.match(/\[tag_([a-z0-9_]+)(?:\s+|\])/);
window.alert(match[1]);​ // alerts "retweet"
```

Answer (score 1):

The regex to capture it would be:

`/.*\[tag_(.*?)\W.*/`

This matches any characters up to the end of `[tag_` and then starts capturing any caracters until it encounters a non-word character, then any other characters.  The match will contain only the releavant parts.

use it like:

`myString.match(/.*\[tag_(.*?)\W.*/)[1]`

Comment: don't you need the `?` to stop it being greedy? ... `/.*\[tag_(.*?)\W.*/` (regex not my thing though :/)

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you're looking for what comes after `[tag_`, up until the next space (or the end of the tag)

So:

```
var tag = '[tag_retweet attr="val" attr2="val"]';
// or var tag = '[tag_share]';
var match = tag.match(/\[tag_(.*?)[\] ]/)[1];
```

Comment: I am getting only `null` http://jsfiddle.net/vaakash/jf6Xe/ or am I doing anything wrong ??

Comment: Apparently JS regexes don't understand that `]` has no special meaning if it is the first character in a character class. See edit.